# Create an NSString with leading zeroes for minutes and seconds

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, cocoa-touch, formatting

I need to constantly update the a playback time in a label. I am getting the time `NSTimeInterval currentProgress = self.moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime;` which returns a double value. But the format in which I need to display is "MM:SS" (00:00). I have tried the following code

```
NSTimeInterval currentProgress = self.moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime;

float min = floor(currentProgress/60);
float sec = round(currentProgress - min * 60);
```

When the progress time is 10 minutes and 10 seconds it displays perfectly fine, as "10:10". But the problem here is if the progress time is 1 minute and 7 seconds, it displays "1:7" in the label. My intended  display is "01:07". How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", (int)min, (int)sec];
```

Try this. Should just work!

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
int seconds = (int)currentProgress % 60;
int minutes = currentProgress / 60;

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
```

The `%02d` format specifier will automatically pad with 0s so that the field as *at least* 2 characters wide.